# What does it mean a "writing sample of recent scholarship"?

Tags: application, job-search, job, faculty-application

I am applying for an assistant professor position in Europe and they ask for "two writing samples of recent scholarship".
I also searched the term on Google but did not find anything useful. What does it really mean?

Comment: If you have any questions about a faculty job application, contact the department and ask for clarification. Ideally you want to offer, what *you* have already thought that writing examples of recent scholarship might be and have them confirm that you are right/wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it just means two recent written works, e.g. papers, book chapters etc.

Comment: @Spark why not make your comment an answer?

Comment: Following @Spark, maybe something from your thesis if you are recently graduated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is simply a request for two examples of your written works, say publications, book chapters, or any other relevant material (I know that for literature applications this can include, perhaps unsurprisingly, literary works).